# Why the id is changing every time on the same phone ? Firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38RGp.jpg)First of all i want to say that my english isn't very good but i hope this is not a problem (i hope). So I wrote a code that "should" get user id from the user of my app but every time 
firebase get other id on the same phone can someone help me with this problem ?
If you need more info, please write it in comments . Thank you in advance. Here my code .

```
EditText editTextName;
Button buttonAdd;
Spinner spinnerGenres;

DatabaseReference databaseArtists;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_one_cent);

    databaseArtists = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("prousers");

    editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    buttonAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddArtist);
    spinnerGenres = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerGenres);

    buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         addArtist();
        }
    });
}

private void addArtist(){
    String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
    String genre = spinnerGenres.getSelectedItem().toString();

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)){

        String id = databaseArtists.push().getKey();

        Artist artist = new Artist(id, name, genre);

        databaseArtists.child(id).setValue(artist);

        Toast.makeText(this, "You are a pro user :D", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        finish();
        System.exit(0);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something's wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

}

and this one too

```
public Artist(){

}

public Artist(String artistId, String artistName, String artistGenre) {
    this.artistId = artistId;
    this.artistName = artistName;
    this.artistGenre = artistGenre;
}

public String getArtistId() {
    return artistId;
}

public String getArtistName() {
    return artistName;
}

public String getArtistGenre() {
    return artistGenre;
}
```

}

Comment: Firebase is behaving correctly, everytime you call push().getKey() a new push key is generated for you.

Comment: but I don't want to have new key every time (on one phone ) i mean if more people use it i can see for ex.: my friends key is 222 so i can see all actions on this key . Do you understand ? (Sorry my english is bad :/)

Comment: I would like to have 1 key for each new user

Comment: Have you tried to implement autehntication and use the `uid` instead of using the random key that is generated by the push method?

Comment: no but is there no other way ? I mean i can try this with autehntication but is there a other way or only this one ?

Comment: can you post screenshot of your database and how you want to show?

Comment: sure . please wait 5 minutes

Comment: Short of implementing authentication, you can generate a UUID in app init and save in preferences (check if exist before creating) - use that to uniquely identify user to firebase.  If user uninstalls/reinstalls then they would get new UUID.

Comment: i just added a photo . sorry about this black thing but my photo should have only 2 MiB

Comment: there are 2 keys(id's) on one phone . i would like to have only 1 key on 1 phone and secound key on secound phone ...

Comment: So it works only with authentication ?